# The password policy is ... valid?

Tags: single-word-requests

What do you say when a password policy is valid?

..is accepted?
..is fullfilled?

**Context**:

> "Password policy: The password is required to be at least 12
>   characters long."
>
> "Password policy failed - the password does not count enough
>   characters."
>
> **"Password policy [...looking for the word here!....], the password is long enough."**

In **German** I'd say (past participle)

> Die (Passwort-) Richtlinie wurde eingehalten.

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "valid" here? Eg, what's an example of a "password policy" and what would make it invalid?

Comment: ***satisfied***.

Comment: I have not seen the term *password policy* and consider it a misnomer. I would call it a *password requirement*. And yes, I agree with , @Dan Bron. The word is *satisfied*.

Comment: @WS2 [Password policy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Password_policy) is a standard term in the world of IT and computer security. In fact, *policy* itself is widespread there, used to indicate a packaged **collection** of requirements and rules applicable to the thing governed. (In other words: no, it is not a misnomer.)

Comment: @Dan Bron: I agree with WS2 that OP's use of *password policy* is clunky. A *policy* is a much broader term that includes numerous factors (such as what to do if the user types an incorrect password, whether to display "hints" or send email links for password reset, etc.). But OP is only interested in the "password format" ***requirements*** of the policy.

Comment: @FumbleFingers A petition which satisfies only the relevant parts of the *policy* is still said to *satisfy* that policy, because the policy is not asking any more of it than it is supplying. This usage is both well-founded in theory and well-established in practice. Having said that, I was mostly informing WS2 of the existence of the term *password policy*, which he initially mentioned was unfamiliar to him (and therefore he summarily labeled a *misnomer*).

Comment: @Dan Bron: I'm not really trying to convince *you* to think the same as me and WS2 - for all I know there's a US/UK usage split or some other reason why you'd be happy with *the password policy has been met*, whereas we'd prefer something more like *the **requirements** of the password policy have been satisfied*. I don't see any reason why a *password* policy should be any different to a car insurance policy, for example. To my mind policies *contain* requirements that can be met or breached, but the policy itself is only "in force" or "invalidated", say, not "met".

Comment: @FumbleFingers Thank you for lending the benefit of your experience to make these points. *Insurance policy* has been around since at least the 16th century. But I have noticed in America that the word *policy* is sometimes used in a more restricted sense than it would be with us. For example shops will have a notice which is headed *Store Policy*. It sounds grand and fundamental, but all it usually applies to are the circumstances in which they will give a refund for returned goods.

Comment: @WS2: You'd be surprised. Text following [*It is store policy to...*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22it+is+store+policy+to%22) include *... charge everyone, give children such gifts on their birthdays, accept small dogs only, wrap all purchases in boxes or fancy packages, take note of a loose button or torn pocket on a customer's old suit,* etc. (I think we've got to accept stores these days go for ***comprehensive** policies!* :)

Comment: Wow, my single-word-request evolved to a really interesting discussion :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could either say,

- Password Policy ***[Met](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/meet)***

  > Fulfil or satisfy (a need, requirement, or condition)

or

- Password Policy ***[Satisfied](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/satisfy)***

  > Adequately meet or comply with (a condition, obligation, or demand)

[ODO]

Both are past participles of ***meet*** and ***satisfy*** respectively.

Comment: Been looking for exactly those words. Thanks to Dan Bron, too.

Comment: You're welcome and thanks for the green check. I hope Dan doesn't mind me getting the rep (it would have been all his had he posted an answer instead of a comment!)

Comment: @BiscuitBoy Dan does not mind at all. In fact, I prefer people to post their own answers rather than nagging me to convert my comments to answers proper! I wish more people took after you. In re: rep, well, I have something like 17K now, and I have yet to figure out how to eat it or spend it. If you work that out, let me know, and we can go back to competing for it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

[**Valid**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/valid) is correct and often used. Why not that?  You can also use **invalid** for the second assertion.

> sound; just; well-founded:

BTW--The phrase ".. the password does not count enough characters" should be "... the password is not long enough".  Also, "Password policy failed" is wrong, since the password *policy* didn't fail, the entered *password* did. I'd try "Password invalid".